# How to remove time from SharePointWebControls field name Modified

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have created a layout page and want to show last modified date (without time) of page

Using below to show last modified date but it is displaying time also

```
<SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField FieldName="Modified" runat="server" />
```

Comment: you need to set `DateOnly` attribute to `true`. Try it as `<SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField FieldName="Modified" DateOnly="true" runat="server" />` and check

Comment: @GautamSheth Getting message 'Sorry, something went wrong' after added DateOnly="true"

Comment: Could be casing, could you modify it as `DateOnly="True"` or `DateOnly="TRUE"` and check ? You can also try it as `<SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField FieldName="Modified" DateOnly="true" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" />` ?

Comment: I have tried it, still getting same error message

Answer (score 1):

We can use JavaScript to remove time from Modified date as below sample code

```
<div class="page-content-footer container">
        <p class="date" id="mslastModifiedDateOnly">Last Reviewed: 
            <SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField FieldName="Modified" runat="server" />
        </p>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery('#mslastModifiedDateOnly').text('Last Reviewed: '+ jQuery('#mslastModifiedDateOnly').text().replace('Last Reviewed: ','').split(' ')[0]);
            });
        </script>
        <hr>
        <div id="pageFeedbackForm" class="form">
            <!-- COMPONENT - Page Feedback -->
        </div>
    </div>
```